# How to clean the virus which opens Nuevaq.fm on IE and blocks many other applications?

Tags: windows, virus, adware

I am facing problem with this virus which has blocked the Task Manager, Firefox and many other applications of my computer. Only, Internet Explorer is working. And whenever I open Internet Explorer it opens Nuevaq.fm where I'm requested to download some ActiveX contoller (an Adware I guess). Please help me to fix this.

Comment: I recommend you to check this [other question](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware), centralizing usual steps to follow about virus and malware cleaning in general. Follow the steps suggested there, and update your question with details on what worked, what didn't.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend running [SmitFraudFix](http://siri.geekstogo.com/SmitfraudFix.php) and [SuperAntiSpyware Portable](http://www.superantispyware.com/portablescanner.html) from a USB drive. The SuperAntiSpyware portable is very difficult for virus/spyware/malware to stop since it's file structure and name changes a couple times a day. SmitFraudFix can remove very stubborn known infections. I've had very good luck using this combination (even without going into safemode) to remove various infections.

After running both, if you are able to install other scanners, MalwareBytes (linked in other comments) is a good scanner to add for another scanning check.

For preventions, I've found [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/security_essentials/) and [SpywareBlaster](http://www.javacoolsoftware.com/spywareblaster.html) very useful and not resource hungry.

All programs are free to use.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Spybot S&D](http://www.safer-networking.org/en/ownmirrors1/index.html). Update it, do a immunization and start a scan. When it is done, install an [Avast Free Antivirus](http://download.cnet.com/Avast-Free-Antivirus/3000-2239_4-10019223.html?part=dl-85737&subj=dl&tag=button). Update it, schedule a boot time scan. Enjoy your coffee, press delete/clean when it asks. (Check what it will delete).

After you played enough with the buttons, your system will load and hopefully everything will be in the normal state. If you use Windows Vista/7, you can use `sfc /scannow` after the scans are done to repair your files (you have to type this in a command prompt!)

If you fail somewhere, you should go with `sfc` right now.

---

Note: **Disconnect your network when you finished updating/downloading the applications. !**

Answer (score 0):

As @Shiki says, get Spybot but I would also add [MalwareBytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/)
and  [Adaware](http://www.lavasoft.com/) and scan with all three.  Be sure to turn off system restore as much of this malware will "hide" there only to return after a reboot.